# Low memory and fastest querying database for a Python project

Tags: python, database, nosql, rdbms

I'm migrating a GAE/Java app to Python (non-GAE) due new pricing, so I'm getting a little server and I would like to find a database that fits the following requirements:

- Low memory usage (or to be tuneable or predictible)
- Fastest querying capability for simple document/tree-like data identified by key (I don't care about performance on writing and I assume it will have indexes)
- Bindings with Pypy 1.6 compatibility (or Python 2.7 at least)

My data goes something like this:

- Id: short key string
- Title
- Creators: an array of another data structure which has an id - used as key -, a name, a site address, etc.
- Tags: array of tags. Each of them can has multiple parent tags, a name, an id too, etc.
- License: a data structure which describes its license (CC, GPL, ... you say it) with name, associated URL, etc.
- Addition time: when it was add in our site.
- Translations: pointers to other entries that are translations of one creation.

My queries are very simple. Usual cases are:

- Filter by tag ordered by addition time.
- Select a few (pagination) ordered by addition time.
- (Maybe, not done already) filter by creator.
- (Not done but planned) some autocomplete features in forms, so I'm going to need search if some fields contains a substring ('LIKE' queries).

The data volume is not big. Right now I have about 50MB of data but I'm planning to have a huge dataset around 10GB.

Also, I want to rebuild this from scratch, so I'm open to any option. What database do you think can meet my requirements?

Edit: I want to do some benchmarks around different options and share the results. I have selected, so far, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Drizzle, Riak and Kyoto Cabinet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Postresql, only because it does what you want, can scale, is fast, rather easy to work with and stable.

It is exceptionally fast at the example queries given, and could be even faster with document querying.

Comment: Nice. Can you give some insight about document querying in PostgreSQL? Just a link will be great.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/index.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/textsearch.html
Google also has some tutorials...

Comment: I did a quick search but Google gets bad results with "document" in the search, getting hits with "documentation", "how-to document", etc. in their content. Thanks for pointing out where to start.

Answer (score 3):

The path of least resistance for migrating an app engine application will probably be using [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/), which implements a major portion of the app engine API.  In particular, you might want to use the [HyperTable](http://hypertable.org/index.html) data-store, which closely mirrors the Google App Engine datastore.

Edit: ok, so you're going for a redesign.  I'd like to go over some of the points you make in your question.

> Low memory usage

That's pretty much the opposite of what you want in a database; You want as much of your dataset in core memory as is possible; This could mean tuning the dataset itself to fit efficiently, or adding `memcached` nodes so that you can spread the dataset across several hosts so that each host has a small enough fraction of the dataset that it fits in core.

To drive this point home, consider that reading a value from ram is about 1000 times faster than reading it from disk; A database that can satisfy every query from core can handle 10 times the workload compared with a database that has to visit the disk for just 1% of its queries.

> I'm planning to have a huge dataset around 10GB.

I don't think that you could call 10GB a 'huge dataset'.  In fact, that's something that could probably fit in the ram of a reasonably large database server;  You wouldn't need more than one memcached node, much less additional persistance nodes (typical disk sizes are in the Terabytes, 100 times larger than this expected dataset.

---

Based on this information, I would definitely advise using a mature database product like PostgreSQL, which would give you plenty of performance for the data you're describing, easily provides all of the features you're talking about.  If the time comes that you need to scale past what PostgreSQL can actually provide, you'll actually have a real workload to analyse to know what the bottlenecks really are.

Comment: Thanks, I was just checking this yesterday. But I'm thinking to do it again from scratch, so I'm fine with a path of "more" resistance ;) Anyway, I'm going to check HyperTable.

Comment: About your new points:

- I want the low memory usage to be able to control myself the cache (with memcached, i.e.)
- 10GB are a big dataset for the data I'm storing :) It looks small, but it isn't.